# Best practice to show ProgressDialogs through an application?

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

In my application I'd like to show a `ProgressDialog` on certain events (during `AsyncTasks` for example). I never want to show multiple `ProgressDialogs` simultaneously.

What is the best and most efficient way to do this?
My current code looks like this:

```
public class ProgressDialogHelper {
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public static void showProgressDialog(Context c) {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(c, null, null);
            progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar);
        }
    }

    public static void dismissProgressDialog() {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling these methods from my other classes to show/dismiss the `ProgressDialog`.

Is this considered good practice? If not, how should I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking for the best practice. In fact the best practice is to not use `ProgressDialog`s, because they block the user from interacting with the app.

There are many alternatives to not use a `ProgressDialog`.

If your app is loading data, which is required for a list, place a `Spinner` instead of the ListView.

For some additional reading in this topic see here: [Google Design Guidelines: Progress](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-types-of-indicators)

---

If you still want to use a `ProgressDialog` i would highly recommend to not use the class you posted above. It holds a `static` reference to a `progressDialog` and so it's global above all activities and live cycles. If your application is recreated or something else this can cause some trouble.

I would recommend an non `static` `ProgressDialogHelper` you can initialize for every `Activity` and this one will then handle the `Dialog`. Also make sure to handle livecycle methods like `onDestroy`

---

Having a BaseActivity as @jagmohan noted is possible, but if you don't want to have your own BaseActivity and want to use something as drop in. You can create something like this:

**ProgressDialogHelper.java**

```
public class ProgressDialogHelper {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public ProgressDialogHelper() {

    }

    public ProgressDialogHelper(Context context, String title, String message) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(title);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(message);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    public ProgressDialog getProgressDialog() {
        return mProgressDialog;
    }

    public void setProgressDialog(ProgressDialog mProgressDialog) {
        //make sure the previous dialog is hidden
        hide();
        this.mProgressDialog = mProgressDialog;
    }

    public void show() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && !mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public void create(Context context, String title, String message) {
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, message);
    }

    public void hide() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give example how to use your class

Comment: @MinaFawzy create a new instance of the helper, and then you simply use create, show, hide, onDestroy

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @mikepenz, using ProgressDialogs is discouraged in the latest design guidelines. However, here is something which worked well for me in the past.

I used to setup a base `Activity` and add couple of methods to hide and show progress dialog in that class.

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected static final String TAG = BaseActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    protected void showProgressDialog(String title, String message) {
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, title, message);
    }

    protected void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // hide progress dialog to prevent leaks
        hideProgressDialog();
    }

    // other stuff...
}
```

Now, you can extend this base activity in the new activity classes you create in your project and use these methods to show/hide progress dialogs.

Btw, just make sure that you call show/hide methods from the UI thread.

Hope this answers your question.